# Как найти нужный или следующий по счету блок на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как найти следующий по счету блок, дан код:

```
html_text = """
<table class="1">
    <tr class="highlight">
        <div>1</div>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highlight">
        <div>1</div>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highlight">
        <div>1</div>
    </tr>
</div>
<table class="2">
    <tr class="highlight">
        <div>1</div>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highlight">
        <div>1</div>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highlight">
        <div>1</div>
    </tr>
</div>
<table class="1">
    <tr class="highlight">
        <div>fd</div>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highlight">
        <div>fdg</div>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highlight">
        <div>fgd</div>
    </tr>
</div>
"""
```

Нужно найти второй по счету блок `<table class="1">` и у него все `<tr class="ВВВ">`
Пробовал так:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')
t2 = soup.findNext("table", class_="1")
tr2 = t2.find_all("tr", class_="highlight")
print(tr2)
```

next_sibling тоже не сработал, реализация с помощью цикла не подходит, так как для первого `<table class="1">` мне нужно сделать одни действия, а для следующего `<table class="1">` - другие

Answer (score 0):

во втором `<table class='1'>` нет `<tr class='BBB'>`. поэтому и не находит

Comment: ошибся при составлении вопроса, исправил